# Visual Studio Community 2015 update 2 crashes on start

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Just installed update 2 and now i can't open VS anymore. Getting this in the log.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-21T14:43:50.178548800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>61639</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-B8F3EGS</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>14.0.25123.0</Data>
    <Data>56f22f32</Data>
    <Data>msenv.dll</Data>
    <Data>14.0.25123.0</Data>
    <Data>56f22f38</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>00409b39</Data>
    <Data>bc8</Data>
    <Data>01d19bdc31f7ea3a</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll</Data>
    <Data>48d9a5c4-ecea-4d3b-b435-98ac6bcddf54</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Tried updating all my drivers, updating python, uninstall with total uninstaller, delete cache, repair.

I'm running Windows 10 with everything up to date i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the /safemode - it will disable 3-rd party extensions. If that will not help, then should be diagnosed with something like crash dump.

Comment: this is more a comment and not really an answer.

Comment: Depends. Few times i was able to find the 3-rd party extension that was the cause with the /safemode. Other reasons i had were the corrupted installation and some completely unrelated that were connected to my own activities. I would say that it is a part of the answer. Or you meant that it should be more detailed?

Comment: I ran in safemode and it started without problems. Couldn't figure out how to disable plugins so i closed and opened without /SafeMode and it worked! Do running /SafeMode disable extensions in the non /SafeMode mode too?